# Boxplots figure dimension and proportion

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to make a single figure formed by 3 boxplots and I utilise the code below, however the final figure has wrong proportion (see below). What function/parameter shall I edit?

```
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 3)))
print(A, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(B, vp = vplayout(1,2))
print(C, vp = vplayout(1,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe a tangent, but you could consider removing the legends from two of the plots. They are the same in all images.

Comment: You should use `facet_grid(...)` or `facet_wrap(...)` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of facetting. This would be *a lot* easier if you had provided your data. Please do so in future!!

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(c("WTN","KON","WTH","KOH"),each=30), 
                 AMP = rnorm(120, sd=20),
                 ADP = rnorm(120, sd=10),
                 ATP = rnorm(120, sd=30))

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
gg.df <- melt(df, id="ID", variable.name="Adenosine")
ggplot(gg.df, aes(x=ID, y=value, fill=ID))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~Adenosine)
```

[image]

Explanation: I'm assuming that your data for AMP, ADP, and ATP are in different columns, and that's why you made the three different ggplots (of course I can't know because you didn't provide your data(!!)). The correct method to deal with this converts your data from "wide" format (data in different columns) to "long" format (all data in one column with a second column to distinguish between the original columns). We use `melt(...)` in the reshape package for that. Then we can fill using `ID` and divide into facets using `Adenosine`.

This pattern: wide-data > long data > ggplot is extremely common. If you plan on using ggplot regularly, you should familiarize yourself with it.